# using glfw in codeblocks on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hyperlink, codeblocks, glfw

It troubles me so much if anyone can help. I spent a lot of time and finally I installed `glfw3` in my Ubuntu 14.04, but when I build a `glfw` project in `codeblocks`, I got this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw

the build log:

> g++ -L/usr/lib -o bin/Debug/myPro obj/Debug/main.o   -lglfw -lGL
>   -lGLU -lpthread -lXxf86vm

I just don't know what's going on here, it's so frustrating, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have only installed the `libglfw` runtime library. To build
applications that link it, you need to install the development
package:

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev
```

The same principle applies to libraries generally.

When you have done this you can remove `-L/usr/lib` from your
linkage options. There is no need to tell the linker to
look in `/usr/lib` for libraries because that is one of the
places where it looks by default.